# Querying tensorflow_model_server text classifier using the Rest API returns Invalid Argument

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am tying to run a `tensorflow` server that can be queried with an array of strings, and for it to return a classification of each of those strings.

My estimator looks like the following:

```
def _initialise_estimator():

   feature_columns = _create_feature_columns()

   # Set run configs. Only keep one checkpoint.
   config = tensorflow.estimator.RunConfig(
      keep_checkpoint_max = 1,
   )

   # Create the estimator.
   estimator = tensorflow.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      hidden_units = [500, 100],
      feature_columns = feature_columns,
      n_classes = 98,
      optimizer = tensorflow.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.003),
      model_dir = _model_location,
      config = config
   )

   return estimator


def _create_feature_columns():
   # Feature column. Assumed to be called description.
   return [tensorflow_hub.text_embedding_column(
      key = 'description',
      module_spec = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1'
   )]

_estimator = _initialise_estimator()
```

I can successfully train the model:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(_pathToData).dropna()
dataset = data[['description', 'class']].copy()

training_input_function = tensorflow.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
   dataset,
   dataset['class'],
   num_epochs = None,
   shuffle = True
)

_estimator.train(
   input_fn = training_input_function,
   steps = 1000
)
```

use it to predict things:

```
descriptions = pandas.DataFrame(['sales', 'equipment'], columns=['description'])

predict_input_fn = tensorflow.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
   descriptions,
   shuffle = False
)

_estimator.predict(input_fn = predict_input_fn)
```

and export the model using `export_savedmodel`:

```
feature_columns = _create_feature_columns()
feature_spec = tensorflow.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)

serving_input_receiver_fn = tensorflow.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

_estimator.export_savedmodel(
   export_dir_base = _export_location,
   serving_input_receiver_fn = serving_input_receiver_fn,
   strip_default_attrs = True,
   as_text = True
)
```

The server is run using the following:

```
tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=prediction --model_base_path=/app/prediction/lib/export
```

which starts the server successfully.

However, when I try and query the server using:

```
curl -d '{"instances": ["sales"]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/prediction:predict
```

I get the following error:

> { "error": "Could not parse example input, value: \'sales\'\n\t [[{{node ParseExample/ParseExample}} = ParseExample[Ndense=1, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_STRING], _output_shapes=[[?,1]], dense_shapes=[[1]], sparse_types=[], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names)]]" }

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have an idea about what format the array of instances should be in? I can't for the life of me get it to work. I suspect its something to do with how I'm saving the model using `export_savedmodel` but I don't know for certain.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have also the same issue....